# Better pattern for the binary copy command for data ingest for Npgsql PostgreSQL C#

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql, .net-6.0

We will have a firehose of data coming in that needs to be ingested into Postgres V14. Using the Npgsql driver and examples I have something like this:

```cs
var connString = "Host=localhost;Username=postgres;Password=******;Database=quotes";
await using var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);
await conn.OpenAsync();
    
await using var importer = await conn.BeginBinaryImportAsync(
                        "COPY quote_datas (symbol,quote_date etc etc)" +
                        "FROM STDIN (FORMAT binary)");
    
foreach (var entry in quoteDatas)
{
    await importer.StartRowAsync();
    await importer.WriteAsync(entry.Symbol);
    if (entry.NineTopDate == null) 
        await importer.WriteNullAsync();
    else
        await importer.WriteAsync((DateTime)entry.QuoteDate, 
                            NpgsqlDbType.Timestamp);
}
    
await importer.CompleteAsync();
```

The problem is the casting is to slow to the NpgsqldbType but I might have nulls and there are 50 columns in the table that might be checked. Is there a better faster way to do this?

Comment: How do you know that “the casting is too slow”?  It would be surprising if your C# was the bottleneck here.

Comment: If I filter out the nulls before hand and run them all straight through, the ingest rate is about 10 times faster.

Comment: Filtering out the nulls also means you're sending less data, which has nothing really to do with the cast.

Comment: Cross posted as a github issue in https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/4278